# Setting number of encoding slices to 1 using ffmpeg libs (libavcodec, libavutil, libavformat)

Tags: c, ffmpeg, encoder, libav

I implemented video encoder in C using libav libs. I could not seem to figure out how to set encoding slices to 1.

Here is what I'm doing while initializing encoder:

```
avcodec_register_all();

enc->codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264); // soft encoding
if (!enc->codec)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
    return 1;
}

enc->pCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(enc->codec);
if (!enc->pCodecCtx)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
    return 1;
}

enc->pCodecCtx->bit_rate = 2000000;
enc->pCodecCtx->width = width;
enc->pCodecCtx->height = height;
enc->pCodecCtx->time_base = (AVRational){1, 30};
enc->pCodecCtx->framerate = (AVRational){30, 1};
enc->pCodecCtx->gop_size = 60;
enc->pCodecCtx->max_b_frames = 0;
enc->pCodecCtx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
enc->pCodecCtx->slices = 1;
enc->pCodecCtx->slice_count = 1;
enc->pCodecCtx->slice_offset = 0;
enc->pCodecCtx->slice_flags = 1;


if (enc->codec->id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264){
    ret = av_opt_set(enc->pCodecCtx->priv_data, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);
    if (ret != 0)
        printf("Could not set av_opt_set()\n");
}
av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_FATAL);

ret = avcodec_open2(enc->pCodecCtx, enc->codec, NULL);
if (ret < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec, ret = %d\n", ret);
    return 1;
}
```

Now, the metadata (on [this](https://mradionov.github.io/h264-bitstream-viewer/) site) shows 8 slices:

[image: 2]

I'm using libavcodec, libavformat and libavutil.

According to [this](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html) documentation I have to change "slice_mode". but I cannot find it anywhere...

Comment: It supposes to be something like `ret = av_opt_set(codecContext->priv_data, "slices", "1", 0);` and `ret = av_opt_set(codecContext->priv_data, "slice_mode", "fixed", 0);` (check `if (ret != 0)...`). The arguments are relevant only for `libopenh264` encoder. Are you sure you are using `libopenh264` encoder?

Comment: Set `thread_type` to `frame` in codecContext.